# Public method to move 3 objects but keep them aligned

Tags: java, variables, instance

I am trying to write a public instance method names **move()**

It takes two integer arguments which showing the amount that the objects needs to change the values of xPos and yPos.

I don't want the method the return a value.

I have done this below but I get the following error message?

*Compilation failed (18/01/2020 15:16:31)
Error: line 1 - method move in class StickFigure cannot be applied to given types;
  required: no arguments
  found: int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length*

Could I get some guidance where I am going wrong.

```
/*Instance variables*/   
 private int xPos;
 private int yPos;

 private Circle head;
 private Triangle body;
 private Rectangle leg;


 public person()
 {
  super(); 
  this.head = new Circle(30, OUColour.PINK);
  this.body = new Triangle (50, 50, OUColour.RED);
  this.leg = new Rectangle (6, 50, OUColour.PINK);
  this.setXPos(25);
  this.setYPos(220);
  this.alignAll();
  }   


  public void setXPos(int newPos)
  {
  this.xPos = newPos;

  this.body.setXPos(newPos);//part (b)(iii)
  }


  public int getXPos()
  {
  return this.xPos; 
  }


  public void setYPos(int newPos)
  {
  this.yPos = newPos;

  this.body.setYPos(newPos);//part (b)(iii)
  }


  public int getYPos()
  {
  return this.yPos;
  }  

  public Circle getHead()
  {
   return this.head;   
}

public Triangle getBody() 
{
   return this.body;   
}

public Rectangle getLeg() 
{
   return this.leg;   
}


public void alignHead() 
{
   this.head.setXPos(this.body.getXPos() + (this.body.getWidth() - this.head.getDiameter())/2);
   this.head.setYPos(this.body.getYPos() - this.head.getDiameter());
  }  

public void alignBody()
{
   this.body.setXPos(25);
   this.body.setYPos(220);
  }

public void alignLeg()
{
   this.leg.setXPos(this.body.getXPos() + (this.body.getWidth() - this.leg.getWidth())/2);
   this.leg.setYPos(this.body.getYPos() + this.leg.getHeight());
  }

public void alignAll()
{
   this.alignBody();
   this.alignHead();      
   this.alignLeg();

  }

   public void move(int newxPos, int newyPos)
   {
   this.body.setXPos(xPos + newxPos);
   this.body.setYPos(yPos + newyPos);
   this.alignAll();
   this.delay(20);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want method `move` to take arguments, you have to declare it:

```
public void move(int xPos, int yPos)
```

instead of

```
public void move()
```

Comment: Thank you I have made this change and am no longer getting that error message. However run the move() method to change the xPos and yPos. I check the variables of the objects and they have not moved? I currently have a object with (xPos 25 and yPos 220) I tried to change them by (5 and 5) but the neither variable increased by 5? any ideas where I am still going wrong?

Comment: You added parameters to your `move` method, now you have to do something with these parameters. For example, rename parameters to `deltaX` and `deltaY` to deal with duplicate names and add following lines to your `move` method: `xPos = xPos + deltaX;` `yPos = yPos + deltaY`

Comment: I have mode the change mentioned below but instead called them newxPos and newyPos. However I think I may have found the problem as to why this change still didn't work. If you look at the public void alignbody() it sets the x and y to 25 and 220 so no matter what I change the x and y to in the move method it is reverted back to the original x and y (25, 220). Is this possibly where I am going wrong? if so any idea how to rectify this?